# SSRS saved data source prompting for credentials

Tags: ssrs

I have a shared data source in SSRS (SQL 2016) that has Windows credentials saved. I can click on that data source, test connection, and it works fine. However, when I attempt to use that data source in a new report it prompts me for credentials anyway.

If you look at the image below, you'll see the prompt window I'm referring to. If I click Test Connection on that screen it works too so I don't understand the issue!

[SSRS prompting for credentials during report creation / modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhpz2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is correct. The stored credentials are for use by the server, not Report Designer.

Comment: Hrmmm, ok... so my intention is to keep the credentials centrally-managed by IT but are you saying that it's inevitable and I would need to provide those credentials to the person(s) creating new reports?

Comment: No. You should give them access to the database via a different account, or grant them access with their active directory account. The account to design the report should not be the same as the one to run the report by regular users.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that but I'm not referring to regular users running the report - I'm talking about the one or two people responsible for writing the reports. For a little background, previously we just did everything with pass-through Windows authentication and that works great. However, we are wanting to have a handful of reports that people can subscribe to which requires the report to have saved credentials.

Comment: To allow Report Designer access to the saved credentials is a security risk. Microsoft's decision to design SSRS server so that it can not divulge the shared credentials under any circumstance increases the security of the overall system.

Comment: Ok, gotcha and agree about the security risk when you put it that way. I appreciate the insight - thanks.